# print the chapter number as name in class file latex

Tags: formatting, chapters

I am using a Duke University LaTeX template for master thesis, the template print chapter headers as follows:

> Chapter 1
>
> chapter name

but I want to print it as follows

> Chapter one: chapter name

I use old style which prints the word "Chapter", any suggestions will be welcomed

```
 %-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 % Chapter format:
 %-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                     \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                             % Done with frontmatter?
                             \if@frontmatter
                                 \@frontmatterfalse
                                  \pagenumbering{arabic}
                                  \setcounter{page}{1}
                             \fi
                     \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                               {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                \else
                  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                \fi
                \chaptermark{#1}%
                \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                \@afterheading
                      \normalbaselines
                      \@textspace  % double-spaced chapter text
 }
 % Format for normal chapters (and appendicies)
 \ifthenelse{\boolean{oldstyle}}{ }
 {%
 \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
 \vspace*{1in} % Leave space at top of page
   { 
   \parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
      \if@inappendix
      % Include the word 'Appendix'
      \makebox[\textwidth][r]{\Huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space\thechapter} 
      \else
      % Don't include the word 'Chapter'
      \makebox[\textwidth][r]{\Huge\bfseries \thechapter} 
      \fi
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 10\p@
\interlinepenalty\@M
 % Title format
 \parbox{\textwidth}{ \flushright{%
  \normalbaselines \LARGE  #1  \par\nobreak }}
\vskip 40\p@
   }%
   \vspace*{50\p@}%
   }

 }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add a minimal example, as @Werner suggests below in comments. A link to a template elsewhere is not adequate for this. First, it isn't minimal. Second, it isn't working (it cannot be compiled as it is, probably). Third, it isn't an example. Perhaps most importantly, fourth, it means that your question is not self-sufficient. It depends on stuff elsewhere which may change or disappear. That means your question is much less likely to help other users in the future. Remember, questions here should concern general issues of interest to others as well as yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Under the `oldstyle` document class option, the [Duke Graduate School LaTeX Template](http://gradschool.duke.edu/academics/theses-and-dissertations) uses the default [`report` class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) chapter settings. What does this look like? Well, let's look at `\@makechapterhead`, the macro responsible for setting the chapter heading:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

The title includes a `\huge\bfseries` CHAPTER (`\@chapapp`) and then the chapter number, followed by a vertical gap and then the `\Huge\bfseries` chapter title. We can adjust this to the following:

```
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \NUMBERstring{chapter}: %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak%\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

The addition of [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) allows us to format the chapter counter representation to be `\NUMBERstring` - something that outputs a string representing the counter number.

Something similar is needed for `\@makeschapterhead` - the macro reponsible for setting the starred chapter headings - in order to have the same font size in the chapter headings:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak%\Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

Add the above two code segments representing the alterations to starred and regular chapters to your preamble. The output should now resemble

[image]

If you use `\numberstring` instead of `\NUMBERstring`, the output resembles

[image]

See the [`fmtcount` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount/fmtcount.pdf) for more options.

Comment: thanks for reply It doesn't work with me, I add it to both .cls file and .tex file (not at the same time) but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3216838: Then you need to provide more information in order for anyone to help you. Please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem as part of your original post.

Comment: I take the template from this website http://gradschool.duke.edu/academics/theses/ "LaTex Template for Thesis/Dissertation" i use oldstyle option to print the word chapter at the heading of each chapter. but i don't know how to convert chapter number to text